# InvalidArgumentException View [layouts.app] not found. Larave-8 LliveWire-2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

When I change `app.blade.php` to `base.blade.php` I am having the following error.

> InvalidArgumentException
> View [layouts.app] not found. (View: D:\Code\my-app\vendor\livewire\livewire\src\Macros\livewire-view-component.blade.php)

> layouts.app was not found.
> Did you mean layouts\base?

Otherwise, it works great.

-Here is my code.
resources\views\layouts\base.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    @livewire('auth.register')
    
    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

resources\views\livewire\auth\register.blade.php

```
<div>
    Registration Form
</div>
```

web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Livewire\Auth\Register;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/register', Register::class);
```

app\Http\Livewire\Auth\Register.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Auth;

use Livewire\Component;

class Register extends Component
{
 public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.auth.register');
    }
}
```

> Note: app.blade.php is still works

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an "out of the box" installation of Livewire to create a full-page component, then the location of the root blade file is hardcoded to **resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php**   It cannot be changed in the basic "zero-configuration" Livewire installation and is the reason why searching for "layout" finds no mention.

If you want to change Livewire's configuration, you have to publish the config file.

```
php artisan livewire:publish --config
```

This gives you a **config/livewire.php** file which is where you will find the default layout file.

```
'layout' => 'layouts.app',
```

which you will need to change to

```
'layout' => 'layouts.base',
```

Further reading

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#page-components

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/installation#publishing-config

Answer (score 1):

You have to search for any that refers to the last app.blade.php source. In some cases, are blades that extends from the main, so maybe that blades have the directives @extends('layout.app') and need be well referenced